# java stream group by and find top 10 in one iteration

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

**It defers from this [How to apply sorting and limiting after groupby using Java streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679962/how-to-apply-sorting-and-limiting-after-groupby-using-java-streams) because I want to solve this problem in exactly one iterations**

Imagine I have following entity:

```
public static class Hospital {
    private AREA area;
    private int patients;

    public Hospital(AREA area, int patients) {
        this.area = area;
        this.patients = patients;
    }

    public AREA getArea() {
        return area;
    }

    public void setArea(AREA area) {
        this.area = area;
    }

    public int getPatients() {
        return patients;
    }

    public void setPatients(int patients) {
        this.patients = patients;
    }
}

public enum AREA {
    AREA1,
    AREA2,
    AREA3
}
```

Now given a list of hospitals I want to find areas with most patients in them, here's what I have done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Hospital> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 20),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA2, 10),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 10),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA3, 40),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA2, 10));
    Map<AREA, Integer> map = findTopTen(list);
    for (AREA area : map.keySet())
        System.out.println(area);

}

public static Map<AREA, Integer> findTopTen(Iterable<Hospital> iterable) {
    Map<AREA, Integer> map = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hospital::getArea,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Hospital::getPatients)));
    for (Map.Entry<AREA, Integer> area : map.entrySet())
        System.out.println(area.getKey() + "...." + area.getValue());
    return map.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted((e1, e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue, (o, o2) -> o,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));

}
```

Clearly I've Iterated two times in order to find top ten areas with most patients in them( once for grouping hospital by area and calculate summation for that group and once more for finding top ten areas).

**Now what I want to know is:**

**1) Is there any better approach to solve this problem in one stream and therefore one iteration?**

**2) Is there any performance benefit for doing it in one iteration, what  is the best practice for solving this kind of problem?(In my point of view on one hand when I call `collect` which is a terminal operation first time it iterates my iterable and saves the intermediate result in another object, in my code I named that object iterationOneResult, so using one stream and calling collect one time will omit that intermediate result which is the main benefit of using stream in java on the other hand solving this problem in one iteration reduce complexity from O(2n) to O(n))**

Comment: If this is purely a complexity-based question, then you might want to create another thread that related to that part (2) and focusses on that aspect. Note, do not forget to create benchmarks when talking about performance on the other hand. For what I would also, suggest for the part (1) is to attempt the solution on the lines of [Holger's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679962/how-to-apply-sorting-and-limiting-after-groupby-using-java-streams#comment110847744_62680202) in the linked question.

Comment: In java Stream API when you call collect the previous iteration is over and the previous stream is closed.  answer and another question link that you mentioned above all have solved this problem in two iteration by calling collect two times. I want to solve this problem in exactly one iteration. please read my question carefully It is not the same as other question that you mentioned. I want to solve this in one iteration @Naman

Answer (score 3):

This can hardly be done in one iteration using stream, but could be more concise using one stream chain

```
Map<AREA, Integer> map = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hospital::getArea, Collectors.summingInt(Hospital::getPatients)))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
        .limit(10)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Also if you want to print intermediate result (just for debugging purposes), you could insert

```
.peek(e -> System.out.println(e.getKey() + " " + e.getValue()))
```

rigth after `.entrySet().stream()`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, btw considering performance I want to do it in one iteration and I want to discuss here if there is performance benefit for doing it that way, in your approach ding collect to times means two seperate iterations. @Ruslan