# Is it possible to group by and find top N in exactly one iteration

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

It defers from this [How to apply to sort and limiting after `groupBy` using Java streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679962/how-to-apply-sorting-and-limiting-after-groupby-using-java-streams) because I want to solve this problem in exactly one iteration. Imagine I have the following entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class Hospital {
    private AREA area;
    private int patients;
}

public enum AREA {
    AREA1, AREA2, AREA3
}
```

Now given a list of hospitals I want to find areas with most patients in them, here's what I have done so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Hospital> list = Arrays.asList(
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 20),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA2, 10),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA1, 10),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA3, 40),
            new Hospital(AREA.AREA2, 10));
    Map<AREA, Integer> map = findTopTen(list);
    for (AREA area : map.keySet())
        System.out.println(area);

}

public static Map<AREA, Integer> findTopTen(Iterable<Hospital> iterable) {
    Map<AREA, Integer> iterationOneResult = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Hospital::getArea,
                    Collectors.summingInt(Hospital::getPatients)));
    return iterationOneResult.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder()))
            .limit(10)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
                    Map.Entry::getValue, (o, o2) -> o,
                    LinkedHashMap::new));

}
```

Clearly I've Iterated two times in order to find the top ten areas with most patients in them( once for grouping hospital by area and calculate summation for that group and once more for finding the top ten areas).

Now what I want to know is:

1. Is there any better approach to solve this problem in one stream and therefore one iteration?
2. Is there any performance benefit for doing it in one iteration, what is the best practice for solving this kind of problem? (In my point of view on one hand when I call `collect` which is a terminal operation first time it iterates my iterable and saves the intermediate result in another object, in my code I named that object iterationOneResult, so using one stream and calling collect one time will omit that intermediate result which is the main benefit of using the stream in java, on the other hand, solving this problem in one iteration make it much faster).

Comment: Replace `(e1, e2) -> e2.getValue() - e1.getValue()` with [`Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html#comparingByValue--) resp. `Map.Entry.comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())`

Comment: Time complexity doesn’t work that way. “O(2n)” is not different than O(n). But your operation isn’t O(n) anyway, as sorting is O(n log n). You can create a custom `PriorityQueue` based collector for the second operation, to only keep the top ten entries in the first place and avoid sorting the entire map. However, that does not imply that the resulting operation needs less time than the simple approach. By the way, did you forget the `limit(10)`?

Comment: @Holger Might be worth ann answer from you, I thought there was a sketch you mentioned in [one of your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62679962/how-to-apply-sorting-and-limiting-after-groupby-using-java-streams#comment110847744_62680202) and it could have been useful, but that was more about how to collect a limited number of values after grouping instead of limited entries altogether.

Comment: @Holger Yes O(n) is equal to O(2n) but. iterationg one time is much faster than iterating two times and O(n log n) is complexity for searching not sorting, btw I have to work out sum for which complexity is O(n) so the total complexity of problem is O(n),

Comment: @tashkhisi sorting would be `O(n log n)` by the implementation in use, so overall complexity must be at par or further higher than that. (aside - I have updated the question to include the `limit` operation).

Comment: I don’t know what you want to say with “O(n log n) is complexity for searching not sorting”. First, I don’t know what “searching” you are referring to, second, just because there is some operation having O(n log n), it does not mean that there can’t be any other operation having O(n log n). The Stream’s `sorted` operation doesn’t specify any algorithm, but there are proofs that it is impossible to have a sort algorithm better than O(n log n) in general.

Comment: @tashkhisi summation is `O(n)` if there is no predictable order in the input provided. (you need to visit all to add their values to the result) (aside - in the favor of usefulness of the question I suggest separating out this in two parts, I can reopen the previous question and you can update them both to address one question at a time.)

Comment: The summing is O(n). And, by the way, the second operation streams over the groups, so while the worst case still is O(n log n), the actual performance is likely much better, as there are less groups than original elements, in practice. Likewise, the actual sorting algorithm has a much better average and best case performance. That’s why assuming that iterating twice was bad, is not useful. The theoretical time complexity does not change and the real life performance can be even better than any attempt to do it in a single iteration. Which doesn’t matter here, as single iteration is impossible

Comment: @Hogler yes I made a mistake  you are right. the overal complexity of first iteration is O(n log n) but wouldn't be better to omit the second iteration and calculate  top 10 in first iteration. I mean second iteration also takes time to run doesn't it?

Comment: The first iteration is O(n) if the source `Iterable` supports O(n) iteration (most collections do). The second is O(n log n), but in practice, the second will process a significantly smaller data set, as it is processing the groups and there are likely less groups than elements in the first stream. And the reference implementation uses TimSort under the hood, which will be much closer to linear performance on average.

Comment: So, when you truly built a single pass solution, e.g. using a `PriorityQueue`, you would have to remove and re-add every item when encountering, as the sort criteria’s value is permanently changing. So, the time complexity still is O(n log n), but here, *n* truly means the number of source elements, even in the best case. So for most practical use cases, the two-iteration solution will be significantly faster.

Comment: @Holger I truly appreciate your time, I completely understand what you are saying but I'm working on big data developing map reduce application in Hadoop mapreduce and I thought maybe it is better to go for performance optimization, but know I'm convinced that I should not change it unless it is necessary.

Comment: If you're doing big data, you shouldn't worry about little loops in Java. If you are going to run this on true big data, you will probably blow your memory up. You should let the grouping and the sorting be done in your parallel nodes, and then performance questions are very different (e.g. shuffling data becomes important).

Answer (score 0):

Let me try to answer your questions, and provide some context on why they're maybe not the right ones:

> 1. Is there any better approach to solve this problem in one stream and therefore one iteration?

The fundamental issue here is that your goal is to find the *groups* with the maximum values, starting with just the raw members of those groups, unsorted. Therefore, before you can find maximum anything, you will need to assign the members to groups. The problem is, which members are in a group determines that group's value - this leads to the logical conclusion that you can't make decisions like "what are the top ten groups" before sorting all your members into groups.

This is one of the reasons that `groupingBy` is a [Collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html) - a collector performs a *terminal operation*, which is a fancy way of saying it consumes the whole stream and returns not a stream but a resolved *something* - it "ends" the stream.

The reason it needs to end the stream (i.e. to wait for the last element before returning its groups) is because it cannot give you group `A` before seeing the last element, because the last element may belong to group `A`. Grouping is an operation which, on an unsorted dataset, cannot be pipelined.

This means that, no matter what you do, there is a hard logical requirement that you will first have to group your items somehow, then find the maximum. This `first, then` order implies two iterations: one over the items, a second over the groups.

> 2. Is there any performance benefit for doing it in one iteration, what is the best practice for solving this kind of problem? (In my point of view on one hand when I call collect which is a terminal operation first time it iterates my iterable and saves the intermediate result in another object, in my code I named that object iterationOneResult, so using one stream and calling collect one time will omit that intermediate result which is the main benefit of using the stream in java, on the other hand, solving this problem in one iteration make it much faster).

Re-read the above: *"two iterations: one over the items, a second over the groups"*. These will always have to happen. However, note that these are two iterations over two different things. Given that you probably have fewer groups than members, the latter iteration will be shorter. Your runtime will not be `O(2n) = O(n)`, but rather `O(f(n, m))`, where `f(n,m)` will be "the cost of sorting the `n` members into `m` groups, plus the cost of finding the maximal `k` groups".

> Is there any performance benefit for doing it in one iteration

Well... no, since as discussed you can't.

> What is the best practice for solving this kind of problem?

I cannot emphasize this enough: **clean code**.

99.9% of the time, you will waste more time optimizing with custom classes than they gain you back in performance, if they can gain you anything at all. The easy gain to be had here is minimizing the number of lines of code, and maximizing how understandable they are to future programmers.